# How to know PPTP client local IP in a LAN assigned automatically by PPTP server?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, lan, pptp

I've configured my PPTP server to automatic assign IP's for the clients.

I'm interested in know what's the current local IP assigned to an specific user. I actually have an script to determine the remote IP but actually I'm not finding the way to find the LAN IP.

That's a sample line in the CHAP file, as you can see, the IP is auto-assigned:

```
test pptpd 0802928d37e151f338696d1601040570 *
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading little bit more (few days later) and there's a PPTP "database" that you can use to do that.

The code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

@line = `/usr/bin/tdbdump /var/run/pppd2.tdb |grep "PEERNAME="`;
foreach $user (@line) {
    chomp ($user);
    undef $name;
    undef $iplocal;
    @record = split (/\;/, $user);

    foreach $field (@record) {
        if ($field =~ /PEERNAME/) {
            $field =~ s/PEERNAME\=//gi;
            $name = $field;
        }
        if ($field =~ /IPREMOTE/) {
            $field =~ s/IPREMOTE\=//gi;
            $field =~ s/(.*)\\.*/$1/gi;
            $iplocal = $field;
        }
    }
    if ((defined $name) && (defined $iplocal)) {
        print ("$iplocal        $name\n");
    }
}
```

I copied the script /usr/bin to run it easy. The sample output will be like that:

```
root@localhost:~# wppp
192.168.0.128        test
```

I hope it help somebody :)